# Disabling allowance of Windows to save power for USB devices via batch loop

Tags: windows, loops, batch-file, usb

Dears,
I was struggling on how to disable allowance of Windows to save power for USB Readers and finally with **RegShot** I managed to find registry inputs which are responsible for those settings so I managed to create two **reg queries** which are scanning Computer:

```
REG QUERY HKLM /v SelectiveSuspendFeatureOn /s
REG QUERY HKLM /v EnableSelectiveSuspend /s
```

Example output:

> C:\Users\asd\Desktop>REG QUERY HKLM /v SelectiveSuspendFeatureOn
>   /s
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\GemCCID
>       SelectiveSuspendFeatureOn    REG_DWORD    0x1
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet002\services\GemCCID
>       SelectiveSuspendFeatureOn    REG_DWORD    0x1
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\GemCCID
>       SelectiveSuspendFeatureOn    REG_DWORD    0x1
>
> End of search: 3 match(es) found.
>
> C:\Users\asd\Desktop>REG QUERY HKLM /v EnableSelectiveSuspend /s
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Enum\IUSB3\ROOT_HUB30\4&22fe6fd&0\Device  Parameters
>       EnableSelectiveSuspend    REG_DWORD    0x1
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet002\Enum\IUSB3\ROOT_HUB30\4&22fe6fd&0\Device  Parameters
>       EnableSelectiveSuspend    REG_DWORD    0x1
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\IUSB3\ROOT_HUB30\4&22fe6fd&0\De vice Parameters
>       EnableSelectiveSuspend    REG_DWORD    0x1
>
> End of search: 3 match(es) found.

So now after I'm able to scan those places and acquire registry paths I want to set them every each of them to 0 so I managed to find and use this .bat :

```
@echo off
cls
:startreg
cls
set regq= REG QUERY HKLM /v SelectiveSuspendFeatureOn /s %curuser%
for /f "tokens=* delims=~" %%A IN ('%regq% ^| findstr /i "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE"') DO set regkey=%%A

Reg add %regkey% /v SelectiveSuspendFeatureOn /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
rem Reg add %regkey% /v EnableSelectiveSuspend /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f

pause
exit
```

Now this is where I stuck, I got two requests/questions related to .bat itself:

1. Each listed item from **REQ QUERY** should be set to 0 with **REG ADD** command - so I believe this should be looped somehow? Out put commands must be generated to .reg file (example below)
2. How to add second option for EnableSelectiveSuspend, is there a way to double-loop this?

@@ EDIT.1 @@

Turned out that some Registry Keys cannot be changed via .bat (path cannot be read) so .reg file should be generated instead:

example of correct .reg file:

> Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\GemCCID]
>   "SelectiveSuspendFeatureOn"=dword:00000000
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet004\services\GemCCID]
>   "SelectiveSuspendFeatureOn"=dword:00000000
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\GemCCID]
>   "SelectiveSuspendFeatureOn"=dword:00000000
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet004\Enum\IUSB3\ROOT_HUB30\4&32305751&0\Device
>   Parameters] "EnableSelectiveSuspend"=dword:00000000
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet004\Enum\USB\VID_0424&PID_2512\5&36b4634f&0&3\Device
>   Parameters] "EnableSelectiveSuspend"=dword:00000000
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet004\Enum\USB\VID_0424&PID_2514\6&234568e7&0&1\Device
>   Parameters] "EnableSelectiveSuspend"=dword:00000000
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\IUSB3\ROOT_HUB30\4&32305751&0\Device
>   Parameters] "EnableSelectiveSuspend"=dword:00000000
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USB\VID_0424&PID_2512\5&36b4634f&0&3\Device
>   Parameters] "EnableSelectiveSuspend"=dword:00000000
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USB\VID_0424&PID_2514\6&234568e7&0&1\Device
>   Parameters] "EnableSelectiveSuspend"=dword:00000000

Looking forward for your answers.

Patryk

@@ EDIT 2 @@

I managed to create logic I needed:

```
@echo off

cls
:startreg
cls
echo Scanning computer in order to apply Power Managment adjustments for USB readers
set NLM=^
set NL=^^^%NLM%%NLM%^%NLM%%NLM%
echo Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00 > %1/scanned.reg
echo. >> %1/scanned.reg
set regq= REG QUERY HKLM /v SelectiveSuspendFeatureOn /s %curuser%
for /f "tokens=* delims=\\n" %%A IN ('%regq% ^| findstr /i "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE"') DO echo [%%A] >> %1/scanned.reg & echo "SelectiveSuspendFeatureOn"=dword:00000000 >> %1/scanned.reg & echo.  >> %1/scanned.reg

set regq= REG QUERY HKLM /v EnableSelectiveSuspend /s %curuser%
for /f "tokens=* delims=\\n" %%A IN ('%regq% ^| findstr /i "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE"') DO echo [%%A] >> %1/scanned.reg & echo "EnableSelectiveSuspend"=dword:00000000 >> %1/scanned.reg & echo.  >> %1/scanned.reg

regedit.exe /S %1/scanned.reg

exit
```

So this one is scanning Windows registry, then saving those values as .reg key and ultimately running the .reg file to apply changes.

After register udpates - restart of system is needed.

This one has argument "path" added so you should run this .bat with argument for example "C:" or any other path.

Comment: Do not change settings in anything other than CurrentControlSet. You appear to be attempting to change settings for multiple devices without knowing what they are. Additionally you appear to have a `\CurrentControlSet004\` key, which could suggest that you may have previously suffered registry corruption. The script you've appended as your edit, sets two variables which aren't used, contains a variable which isn't defined and appears to take a parameter as input, with no validation before running.

Comment: Dear Compo,
this is meant to find USB HUBs and devices and disable allowance of Windows to save power for those devices instead of navigating trough Device Manager and doing it manually for several devices.
You are reffering to variables which aren't you used but haven't you spotted that .reg file is being generated meanwhile? 
Parameter as an input is a {path} variable which is needed for my installation.

Comment: I know what the file is intended to do, and that you are taking a path as an input parameter **%1**. Please tell me the purpose of **%NLM%**, **%NL%**and **%curuser%**. If you mean that I haven't spotted that you are echoing things to a reg file then you are mistaken. I am also fully aware of the purpose of the CurrentControlSet keys and how they work, and that any corruption with one set would mean that the other set would be used for the fix. *(corrupting more than one set would therefore be unwise)*.

Comment: Also like I said, you don't know what any of those devices are, you're just blanket changing the state of every single device without any idea of the repercussions of doing so, whilst that's your perogative, it is also my right to warn you against doing so. In your query of the registry you are also performing a recursive sub key search of the entire root key despite the fact you know that every required value is located within the SYSTEM branch. In your actual created registy file, *you have blindly imported*, did you notice that there is no value data in it?

Comment: If your second edit solved your problem you can post it as an answer and accept it.

Comment: Please remove `SOLVED` from your title and post your solution as a proper answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to create logic I needed:

```
@echo off

cls
:startreg
cls
echo Scanning computer in order to apply Power Managment adjustments for USB readers
echo Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00 > %1/scanned.reg
echo. >> %1/scanned.reg
set regq= REG QUERY HKLM /v SelectiveSuspendFeatureOn /s %curuser%
for /f "tokens=* delims=\\n" %%A IN ('%regq% ^| findstr /i "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE"') DO echo [%%A] >> %1/scanned.reg & echo "SelectiveSuspendFeatureOn"=dword:00000000 >> %1/scanned.reg & echo.  >> %1/scanned.reg

set regq= REG QUERY HKLM /v EnableSelectiveSuspend /s %curuser%
for /f "tokens=* delims=\\n" %%A IN ('%regq% ^| findstr /i "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE"') DO echo [%%A] >> %1/scanned.reg & echo "EnableSelectiveSuspend"=dword:00000000 >> %1/scanned.reg & echo.  >> %1/scanned.reg

regedit.exe /S %1/scanned.reg

exit
```

So this one is scanning Windows registry, then saving those values as .reg key and ultimately running the .reg file to apply changes.

After register udpates - restart of system is needed.

This one has argument "path" added so you should run this .bat with argument for example "C:" or any other path.